# dropbear: "Pubkey auth bad signature for 'root'"

Tags: ssh, putty

In a very rare situation I can't log in to my router using public key authentication. 
I'm using PuTTy 0.63 on client (key stored in pageant), and a Tomato (by Shibby) firmware with a builtin dropbear(v2013.62) on server side.

When this error happens, I see two messages:

On the server's security log:
"127.0.0.1 authpriv.warning dropbear[24621]: Pubkey auth bad signature for 'root' with key md5 ..."

In PuTTy window:
"Server refused public-key signature despite accepting key!"

In most cases I have no problem with this key pair, but sometimes... in the security log I found three occurance of this failure since last september.
I don't know if it is important or not: I'm using wireless connection (WPA2-AES) to my router.

I'm a little bit paranoid ;)
What could it be? Bug? Communication problem? Somebody try to crack my connection?

Comment: I am seeing the same thing with PuTTy and dropbear on a different ARM Linux system. Would love to know why.